# How do I Regex this Facebook fbclid?

Tags: regex

I migrated a clients site from a Movable Type site with posts that ended in ".php" to a WordPress site that ends in a slash "/". All my 301 redirects are working great but i found out from the client he has links in his websites Facebook page. Those links end in ".php?fbclid=InsertRandomParamsHere". What I need to do is replace the ".php" with "/" and the pages will redirect correctly while maintaining the Facebook tracking parameters at the end.

I've been using a regular expression for the 301 and here is what my regex looks like so far (I'm using Rank Math plugin for redirects):

**The Source URL regex is:**

```
^(.*)\.php(.*)
```

**The Destination URL is:**

https://www.beachwoodreporter.com/

What I get right now is, for an example link:

http://www.beachwoodreporter.com/music/you_turn_me_on_again.php?fbclid=IwAR37SDAQdPrxMqwHQEY6dcs5rle1Mt0b0WubR9dL8WbaX3zoKNqjW0J84p0

which should redirect to:

http://www.beachwoodreporter.com/music/you_turn_me_on_again/?fbclid=IwAR37SDAQdPrxMqwHQEY6dcs5rle1Mt0b0WubR9dL8WbaX3zoKNqjW0J84p0

is instead redirecting to:

http://www.beachwoodreporter.com/?fbclid=IwAR37SDAQdPrxMqwHQEY6dcs5rle1Mt0b0WubR9dL8WbaX3zoKNqjW0J84p0

so it's basically stripping out the slug portion of the URL:

/music/you_turn_me_on_again/

And the client has many links like this on their Facebook site trying to do one at a time is out of the question. All I need is to replace the ".php" with "/" and it should fix all these problems. Can what I want be done or should I tell the client I can't do it?

[Image of the Rank Math regex settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P277V.jpg)

Comment: What are you using to perform the regex?  According to [this](https://regex101.com/r/wVzQRt/1), it should be correctly isolating the `.php` part.

Comment: Not sure by what you mean "What are you using to perform the regex?"? I'm using the same tool as you to test regex - https://regex101.com/r/DYGgVf/1.

Comment: Well that's showing you that the first capturing group is capturing everything before `.php`, including the slug portion.  So I don't understand why you seem to be saying that the regex is removing that part.

Comment: I have the regex in place on the website but it's redirecting all this pages to the home page. Try this out: https://www.beachwoodreporter.com/music/you_turn_me_on_again.php?fbclid=IwAR37SDAQdPrxMqwHQEY6dcs5rle1Mt0b0WubR9dL8WbaX3zoKNqjW0J84p0 this link goes to the home page which is wrong.

Comment: Here's a link to the regex settings in the site. https://i.stack.imgur.com/P277V.jpg. Let me know if you can figure oout what is wrong.